# How should I spend my time in Calgary in August?

Tags: sightseeing, canada, toronto

Three questions could explain better my situation:

1. How far Banff is from Calgary and if it's worth the detour, how to get there, are there any activities to do, and how much is it?
2. I will be staying in Toronto and want to know how far are the Niagara Falls and how to get here (suggestions on other places to visit is open).
3. I will be staying from 9th to 16 on Calgary and 17th till 22 in Toronto; how do you recommend I distribute my activities on those time lapses?

Comment: Can you be more specific? This question is very broad, and in this form it will be closed - there is no right answer for it.

Comment: What days will you be going to Calgary / Toronto?

Comment: Suggested revisions- three questions, one asking how far Banff is from Calgary and if it's worth the detour, how to get there etc; one asking the same for something nearish Toronto like Niagara Falls; and a third asking how to split your time between Calgary and Toronto (which are about a thousand miles apart)

Comment: three actual questions - since this one has a Banff answer, edit it to just your #1 then ask #2 and #3 as separate questions that will be tagged differently and answered independently.

Comment: What's the use of bringing up such old questions without providing any value added???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Banff is about [90 minutes from Calgary](http://maps.google.ca/maps?q=Calgary,%20Alberta%20to%20Banff,%20Alberta&saddr=Calgary,%20Alberta&daddr=Banff,%20Alberta&hl=en&sll=49.891235,-97.15369&sspn=47.489197,79.013672&geocode=FYjiCgMd-p8z-SnVP4SfA3BxUzE6tlK2sTttJg;FUjqDAMdGIMc-Sn9SgyRRcpwUzFjlKzavq6vyg&t=h&z=9), and is worth visiting if you're not going to be back in Calgary anytime soon.

The normal list of Calgary attractions:

- Calgary Zoo
- Canada Olympic Park
- Spruce Meadows
- Telus World of Science
- Fort Calgary

More information: http://www.calgaryattractions.com/